# Setting a Select Option Value to a Variable

Tags: javascript, html-select, mootools

Is it possible to set the value of a Select Option equal to a predefined variable, then use its method? Here's an example:

```
<select class='hidden' id='teamChoice' onchange='chooseTeam()'>
<option value="" selected>What team</option>
    <option value='bostonCeltics'>Boston Celtics</option>
</select>


var bostonCeltics = {
    conferencePA: "5=Conference=Eastern",
    divisionPA: "5=Division=Atlantic"
}

function chooseTeam() {
    switch ($('teamChoice').selectedIndex) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            $('PAType=Name=Value3').innerHTML = this.conferencePA;
            break;
    }
}
```

Ideally, on selecting the option titled Boston Celtics, I could use a method to access the different properties of the variable object bostonCeltics. Is this possible?

Comment: Those do not look like valid DOM selectors - which library is your `$`?

Comment: @Pete: Looks like prototype.js, but the OP should tag the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Mootools user, but I think I understand what you're getting at, and believe I can point you in the right direction.

In Javascript, you can access any object property directory, OR by using array notation.  In other words, given `foo = { bar: 1, baz: 2 }`, the following are equivalent:

```
console.log( foo.bar );      // prints 1
console.log( foo["bar"] );   // prints 1
var s = "bar";
console.log( foo[s] );       // prints 1
```

Things get trickier because you define `bostonCeltics` as a `var`, meaning it's not necessarily a property of any object.  You can still accomplish what you want with `eval`, though the use of `eval` is discouraged:

```
var s = "bostonCeltics";
console.log( eval( s + ".conferencePA" ) );    // prints "5=Conference=Eastern"
```

Personally, I would move `bostonCeltics` into a parent object, and use the array notation to access its properties, then what you want to do is pretty straightforward.  To wit:

```
var teams = {
    bostonCeltics = {
        conferencePA: "5=Conference=Eastern",
        divisionPA: "5=Division=Atlantic"
    }       
    // more teams go here
}

function chooseTeam() {
    var tc = $('teamChoice');
    var val = tc[tc.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log( teams[val].conferencePA );    // prints "5=Conference=Eastern"
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle of this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/sQvBZ/

I hope this gets to the heart of what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. A method I seetled on was using 'eval($('teamChoice').options[$('teamChoice').selectedIndex].value).conferencePA;' which gets it done. Thank you much.

Comment: No problem, James.  If it was helpful, you could show some love by accepting my answer, and/or giving me a +1!